# Source Image from <li> list style image attr to be displayed in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've been researching this all night. Normally I'm able to find the answer or derive it from the answer of questions containing similar code but for this I've come up empty.

I have an UL that each LI has its own "list-style-image: url()" attribute. The goal is that when I hover over each different list item, the image associated with said LI will appear larger in an adjacent DIV.

I figured this would be simple to do with jQuery but either its not or I'm straight missing something. I'm also open to ideas using pure javascript.

With stackoverflow being where I end up finding most of my answers, I figured I'd start here. Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

[JS Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/dankbawls/y635mL14/)

HTML:

```
<div class="source">
 <ul class="source-ul">
   <li style="list-style-image: url(example.svg)">image sourced</li>
   <li style="list-style-image: url(example2.svg)">from these list items</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div2 class="appear">
 <img src=""/>
</div>
```

jQuery(so far):

```
var main = function() {
  $('li').hover(function() {
    var svgimage = $(this).attr("li[list-style-image]");
    $('.appear img').attr("src", svgimage);
  });
};

$(document).ready(main)
```

Comment: your code is not working on hover.

Comment: I know, but I'm not entirely sure why, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this add an attribute as `data-src` on each `li` element and than replace `img` src with hovered `li`'s `data-src` attribute.

please find below snippet for more information

```js
var main = function() {
  $('li').hover(function() {
    var svgimage = $(this).attr("data-src");
    $('.appear img').attr("src", svgimage);
   
  });
};

$(document).ready(main)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div>
    <h2>Div containing UL</h2>
    <ul>
      <li data-src="http://bhuck.com/svg/layers.svg" style="list-style-image: url(http://bhuck.com/svg/layers.svg)">List with</li>
      <li data-src="http://bhuck.com/svg/server.svg" style="list-style-image: url(http://bhuck.com/svg/server.svg)">style images</li>
      <li data-src="http://bhuck.com/svg/share.svg" style="list-style-image: url(http://bhuck.com/svg/share.svg)">to be used as source</li>
      <li data-src="http://bhuck.com/svg/stack.svg" style="list-style-image: url(http://bhuck.com/svg/stack.svg)">when hovered over</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="appear">
    <h2>Div to have images appear on</h2>
    <img src="http://bhuck.com/svg/share.svg" height="48" width="48">
    <p>Willing to use an img element if necessary</p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: @bhuck.cdouble ohh that's great glad it helps you please marked as answer for future references

Answer (score 2):

Your current implementation is not working because of the `.attr()` selector you're using.

Since `list-style-image` is a CSS property and not technically an element attribute, you can use the `.css()` method to access it instead, like so:

```
var svgImage = $(this).css("list-style-image");
```

This is only part of the puzzle though - the value of `svgImage` will now include the `url("...")` wrapper around the URL you want. I'd use JavaScript's `.match()` function for this, but you can nab the URL out of there lots of other ways.

Here's a working version of your jQuery example above:

```
    var main = function() {
      $('li').hover(function() {
        var svgimage = $(this).css("list-style-image"),
            svgUrl = svgimage.match(/url\("(.*)"\)/i)[1];
        $('.appear img').attr("src", svgUrl);
      });
    };
```

And an updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e0dtawp6/

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Since I have the "style" directly in my HTML and not my stylesheet, I figured attr is what I had to go with. The .match function is definitely something I'm going to research for future use.

Answer (score 2):

Pure javascript solution might be like that. [Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y635mL14/10/)

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("li"), function(e) {
 e.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
   document.getElementsByClassName('appear')[0].querySelector('img').src = e.style.listStyleImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");;
  document.getElementsByClassName('appear')[0].querySelector('p').innerHTML = "Loaded: "+e.style.listStyleImage;  
});
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <h2>Div containing UL</h2>
    <ul>
      <li style="list-style-image: url(http://bhuck.com/svg/layers.svg)">List with</li>
      <li style="list-style-image: url(http://bhuck.com/svg/server.svg)">style images</li>
      <li style="list-style-image: url(http://bhuck.com/svg/share.svg)">to be used as source</li>
      <li style="list-style-image: url(http://bhuck.com/svg/stack.svg)">when hovered over</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="appear">
    <h2>Div to have images appear on</h2>
    <img src="http://bhuck.com/svg/share.svg" height="48" width="48">
    <p>Willing to use an img element if necessary</p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I'm still learning javascript so your code is a bit above my current level but even seeing it in action helps a ton for me to break it down to fully understand it. Thank you!

Comment: actually those lines are enough straightforward - you've already used most of them in terms of jQuery. e.g. `$('#foo').hover(function(f){ ... })` is almost an equivalent of `document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('onmouseover', function(f) { ... })`. 
jQuery version might seem more compact but when it comes to speed and explicity - raw javascript is winner. 
do not poison yourself with jQuery -))

Comment: Awesome, thanks for taking the time to explain it! I thought jQuery would be faster to use but obviously JS is more powerful so it's clearly the better choice in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `url` part from `li` wrong, it is a `style` attribute and you can get it like this.

```js
var main = function() {
  $('li').hover(function(event) {
    var rawURL = $(event.currentTarget).css('list-style-image');
    var url = rawURL.match(/url\("(.*)"\)/i)[1];
    $('.appear img').attr("src", url);
  });
};

$(document).ready(main)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="source">
 <ul class="source-ul">
   <li style="list-style-image: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/bullet_red.png)">image sourced</li>
   <li style="list-style-image: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/momenticons-gloss-basic/momenticons-gloss-basic/32/bullet-green.png)">from these list items</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="appear">
 <img src=""/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **attr** use **css** to get css attribute of element.

Try This :

```
  var main = function() {
  $('li').hover(function() {
    var svgimage = $(this).css("list-style-image");
    // remove url() using regular expression
    svgimage = svgimage.replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace(/\"/gi, "");
    $('.appear img').attr("src", svgimage);
  });
};
```